# How to specify link function in ggplot GLM graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm, smoothing

How can I select the link function for my ggplot GLM graph? In my case I would like to use logit function for quasibinomial family.

Example data:

```
research_year <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
relative_number <- c(0.1, 0.15, 0.16, 0.23, 0.30, 0.35, 0.36, 0.38, 0.42)
relative_data <-  data.frame(research_year, relative_number)

relative_data
```

Used code:

```
ggplot(data=relative_data, aes(x= research_year, y= relative_number)) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'glm',  method.args = list(family = "quasibinomial"))
```

Comment: Isn't logit the default link function for the quasibinomial family? [`?family`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/family.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the corresponding family function (though the logit link is the default for the quasibinomial, see `?family`).

```
ggplot(data = relative_data, aes(x = research_year, y = relative_number)) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'glm',  
              method.args = list(family = quasibinomial(link = 'logit'))
```

For comparison, try plugging in `link = 'probit'`.